# Cannot iterate a temp NODE to iterate in a Linked List of nodes but if I do parent->child->next->next = result it works

Tags: c, linked-list, tree

I have a problem that I cannot introduce a temp `NODE*` and iterate to find the next `NODE` that is NULL (I marked it in the code with comment).

But, if I do:

`parent->child->next->next = result`

It works completely fine.

Any help?

```
typedef struct tNODE {
    char* inner_text;
    char* tag;
    struct tNODE* parent;
    struct tNODE* child;    
    struct tNODE* next;

}NODE;


NODE* new_node(NODE* parent){
    
    NODE* result = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    result->inner_text = NULL;
    result->tag = NULL;
    result->parent = parent;
    result->child = NULL;
    result->next = NULL;
    if (parent != NULL){
        if (parent->child == NULL){
            parent->child = result;
        } else {
            if (parent->child->next == NULL){
                parent->child->next = result;
                return result;
            }  else {
                //HERE IS THE PROBLEM. A TEMP NODE DOES NOT WORK
                //BUT parent->child->next->next = result works. WHY ? what should i do
                NODE* temp = parent->child->next;
                while(temp != NULL){
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                temp = result;
            }              
        }  
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1. Pick **a** (singular) language. 2. `temp = result` means nothing to the actual list. It is a *temporary* pointer (stress the word *temporary*) that hold an address *copied* from somewhere in the data structure from the prior code and loop. Once that is done, you overwrite the *temporary* pointer with a value that changes *nothing* in the actual list. Pointers aren't magic, and without dereference operations you're just copying *values*, It is no different than `int b = 5; int a = b; a = 42;` and expecting `b` to be `42` afterward.

Comment: Linked lists are best written first with pen and paper. Literally draw the operations, and then make them into code. I would also suggest you choose either C or C++ for your language tag. This might be an acceptable implementation of a linked list in C, but it's not very good as a C++ linked list.

Comment: Why are you trying to iterate your list with if/else statements and not a loop? Are you really going to if/else your way 100 nodes deep? 1,000? 100,000?

Comment: You iterate with `while(temp != NULL)` and then immediately overwrite with `temp = result;` and then `temp` goes out of scope. It's unclear what it is intended to achieve, because it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the `child` pointer. Or the dynamic programming tag.

Comment: @sweenish The data structure is a row based "tree". In reality it is a linked list of linked lists. Each node has a potential "child" linked list, each node of which points back to the parent via `parent`, it's siblings via `next`, and it's own child linked list via `child` (which could have been *much* better named "children").

Answer (score 2):

If the parent has no children, you set the new node as the 1st child.  OK.

If the parent has 1 child, you set the new node as the 2nd child.  OK.

But, if the parent has more than 2 children, you are looping to the end of the child list, which is where you are going wrong.  You are setting `temp` to point at each child in the list, and break the loop only when `temp` becomes `NULL`, meaning it is not pointing at any node at all, as you went beyond the end of your list.  You lost track of the last child in the list.  And then you are setting `temp` to point at the new node, but `temp` does not refer to the last child's `next` pointer in the list, so assigning it a value does not update the list at all.

Your logic needs to look more like this instead:

```
NODE* new_node(NODE* parent){

    NODE* result = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (!result)
        return NULL;

    // in C++, use this instead:
    // NODE* result = new NODE;

    result->inner_text = NULL;
    result->tag = NULL;
    result->parent = parent;
    result->child = NULL;
    result->next = NULL;

    if (parent){
        // if no children yet, assign the
        // new node as the first child ...
        if (!parent->child){
            parent->child = result;
        } else {
            // find the last child ...
            NODE *temp = parent->child;
            while (temp->next){
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            // ... and set it to point at the
            // new node as the next child ...
            temp->next = result;
        }  
    }

    return result;
}
```

That being said, the logic can be simplified a bit more.  Try this instead:

```
NODE* new_node(NODE* parent){
    
    NODE* result = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (!result)
        return NULL;

    result->inner_text = NULL;
    result->tag = NULL;
    result->parent = parent;
    result->child = NULL;
    result->next = NULL;

    if (parent){
        // find the last NODE* pointer that is NULL ...
        NODE **temp = &(parent->child);
        while (*temp) {
            temp = &((*temp)->next);
        }
        // ... and set it to point at the new node ...
        *temp = result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And, if you are free to add another member to your `NODE` type, the logic becomes even simpler as the entire loop can then be eliminated completely, eg:

```
typedef struct tNODE {
    char* inner_text;
    char* tag;
    struct tNODE* parent;
    struct tNODE* first_child;
    struct tNODE* last_child;
    struct tNODE* next;

}NODE;

NODE* new_node(NODE* parent){
    
    NODE* result = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (!result)
        return NULL;

    result->inner_text = NULL;
    result->tag = NULL;
    result->parent = parent;
    result->first_child = NULL;
    result->last_child = NULL;
    result->next = NULL;

    if (parent){
        NODE **temp = (parent->last_child)
            ? &(parent->last_child->next)
            : &(parent->first_child);
        *temp = result;
        parent->last_child = result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Props on the latter. Note based on the ambiguity of the real problem, there is a good chance it could be made even simpler, since the OP said nothing about requisite ordering (e.g., that the new node *must* be appended to the end of the list). I.e. there is decent chance just setting `result->next = parent->child; parent->child = result;` would also suffice.

Comment: @WhozCraig sure, if the new node is meant to be inserted at the front of the list instead of the back. But then, if you take ordering into account then you also have to account for inserting in the middle of the list, which takes even more work. In any case, in this particular situation, I would have added a `last_child` member to `NODE` to avoid having to iterate the whole list at all.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment to `temp` can never change the linked list. To modify the linked list you need to dereference `temp` when it still points to the tail node, and then assign to its `next` member.

So that means you need to stop the loop one iteration earlier:

```c
                NODE* temp = parent->child;
                while (temp->next != NULL) {
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                temp->next = result;
```

Note that you don't need the innermost `if` as a special case. The case where `parent->child->next == NULL` can be dealt with using the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the two alternatives, they are quite different

```
parent->child->next->next = result;
```

and

```
NODE* temp = parent->child->next;
while(temp != NULL){
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp = result;
```

The first one assigns to the `next` field of `parent->child->next`. The second assigns to the **temp variable**. These are not the same thing, it doesn't matter where the `temp` variable is pointing to when you make the assignment, the `temp` variable is not any part of your linked list.

Here is what your code should look like

```
NODE* temp = parent->child;
while(temp->next != NULL){
    temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next = result;
```

In this code `temp` points to the node whose next field you want to change.